# How to restore clustered queue to its pre-cluster state in IBM MQ using linux?

Tags: ibm-mq

` I need to restore clustered queues to its pre-cluster state which was previously removed from cluster. Is there any option to restore those removed queue to its cluster state. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you only want to share the queue in the cluster again? Why not just alter the queue and set the CLUSTER property on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restore queues to the cluster that were previously part of the cluster using a backup created with the `dmpmqcfg` program prior to removing the queues from the cluster.  This backup is only as current as of the date of your backup.

This command will output all queues:

```
dmpmqcfg -m <QMGR> -n TEST.QUEUE -t queue -a -x all -o 1line
```

This command will output only queues that have either `CLUSTER` or `CLUSNL` set to any value:

```
dmpmqcfg -m <QMGR> -t queue -a -z all -o 1line | grep "^DEFINE" | egrep -v "CLUSNL\(' '\) CLUSTER\(' '\)|^DEFINE QMODEL"
```

Running the commands generated prior to removing the queue(s) from the cluster would put them back into the cluster.

***Note that this assumes that if you are using `CLUSNL` that you did not delete the `NAMELIST`***